# Getting an error when trying to create derby account in SnapLogic

Tags: mysql, jdbc, derby, snaplogic

When I try to create a derby account in SnapLogic through the JDBC snap, I get the following error:

```
POST for http://prodxl-ccproxy4.fullsail.snaplogic.com:8087/api/1/rest/account/validate failed: Server Error.
```

Comment: Here, I'm trying to create one derby db account

Answer (score 0):

So, here I have posted some error. It is because, we have to use `derbyClient.jar` instead `derby.jar`. When we want to run derby with specific to server.

Otherwise, we can use `derby.jar` only.

Comment: For more background information about the difference between the `derby.jar` ("Embedded") configuration and the `derbyClient.jar` ("Client-Server", or "Network Server") configuration, please see: https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/getstart/cgsquck70629.html